# Expo - React Native Firebase - Native module cannot be null

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-native-module

I installed @react-native-firebase/auth and I get all the time these errors

> Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
>
> - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
>
> Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen
> if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called. at
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in
>   reportException at
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:172:19
>   in handleException at
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
>   handleError at
>   node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:49:36 in
>   ErrorUtils.reportFatalError

I already googled a lot, pod installed, linked manually, removed, what ever it took.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.5.8",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.7",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.13.0",
    "@firebase/auth": "^0.19.4",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-apple-authentication": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-av": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~10.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "graphql": "^16.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-parallax-scroll-view": "^0.21.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "rn-tourguide": "^3.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Updated: 17.02.2022** So everyone how is facing this issues, I got the answer to clarify that Expo Go doesn't support native modules. So it wasn't rather the issue itself but more with Expo. It is recommended to switch to EAS build and not more Expo Go.